# Why DMI instead of a PCIe link

Tags: pcie, intel

In some Intel chipsets the CPU is connected to the Platform Controller Hub (PCH) by a link called Direct Media Interface (DMI). Based on what I found when researching about it, It's a link very similar to PCIe but not from a hardware perspective. However, logically it is considered and configured as such.

The thing that I don't understand is why couldn't the link just be a PCIe bus why do we need something different yet working very much the same. How is DMI different from a PCIe link.

Comment: Because by going proprietary they don't have to conform to somebody else's specification? Just a guess.

Comment: And, no one else can make a chipset for their CPUs.